# How to convert json string to List<Map<String, Object>> in salesforce apex class?

Tags: apex, trigger, visualforce-component

I have this json string.

```
[
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Abc_SS",
    "description":"Abc"
  },
  {
    "id":100,
    "name":"sales",
    "description":"sales"
  }
]
```

How I can convert this json to `List<Map<String, Object>>`.
Is it possible?

Comment: Nope, the JSON string contains a list of Objects.

Comment: Basically, apparently with Apex `JSON.deserialize` needs a concrete type and doesn't allow `object` :/ So you need to define a type

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible explicitly, however, you can deserialize you String into **List< Object>** and then cast your Object in for-loop to **Map< String, Object>**:

```
String jsonString = '[{"id":2,"name":"Abc_SS","description":"Abc"},{"id":100,"name":"sales","description":"sales"}]';

List<Object> items = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

for (Object itemObj : items) {
    Map<String, Object> item = (Map<String, Object>) itemObj;
    //now you can work with it like you always work with Map
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My overlapping answer that converts to the list of map of string to object is very like Mariia's:

```
String theJsonString = '[{"id":2, "name":"Abc_SS", "description":"Abc"}, {"id":100, "name":"sales", "description":"sales"}]';
Object theJsonObject = JSON.deserializeUntyped(theJsonString);
List<Object> theJsonList = (List<Object>) theJsonObject;
List<Map<String, Object>> theJsonMapList = new List<Map<String, Object>>();

for (Object obj : theJsonList) {
    theJsonMapList.add((Map<String, Object>) obj);
}

System.debug(theJsonMapList);
```

As she said, you have to do it in steps as there's no way to just do a cast.